# Using sqlkata without Dapper

Tags: c#, sqlkata

I think that sqlkata is a nice product, but the nugget package  comes with dapper.

I want to use only the sql builder, someone have a idea ?

Comment: The SqlKata package has **no** dependencies https://www.nuget.org/packages/SqlKata/1.1.7

Comment: You can use it to build just SQL strings, include the `SqlKata` package,
the dapper dependency comes from `SqlKata.Execution` package and it's totally optional

Comment: thanks, i will try